# Is it wrong to use "one" and "had attained" in place of "a" and "attained"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, articles, past-tense

> I used to have one credit card, but I dropped it in the designated box after I had attained my objective.

Is it wrong to use ***one*** and ***had attained***?

Comment: Better with "a" and I'd replace 'after' with "once"= *I used to have a credit card but dropped it… once I (had) attained my objective*. Still a weird type of statement but it's grammatical.

Comment: "One" might be a better choice than "a" if you wanted to emphasise the fact you only ever had **one** credit card (rather just having had this credit card that was destroyed, possibly along with others).

Answer (score -1):

From your statement, I would guess that you do not have any credit cards now. You used to have 1. But now you do not.

I am not sure why you would place your 1 credit card into a designated box. I would destroy my credit card rather than put it in a box I do not control. Unless it was my box, but then I would still possess the credit card. It would still be mine even though it is in my special box that I designated for my credit card. So then the statement "I used to have one credit card" is invalid.

Comment: I dropped the credit card in the box after cutting the card into two because i did not want to use the card any more.The box is owned by the Bank.Now I have 3 [THREE} debit cards

Comment: The bank box is designated for this special purpose. The rejected credit cards are cut into two parts and dropped in that box

Comment: The question started with"Is it wrong to use"and ended with a mark of interogation. english.stackexchange.com/revisions/450/803/1-sumelic-june20 at21:17 REVISED BY sumelic

Comment: This post discusses the events / actions *described* by the sentence,  and not the ***language*** used by the sentence;  therefore, it is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -3):

"One" has a different meaning to "I". It's closer to "people". So in your example it wouldn't make sense unless you altered the first pronoun and other elements as well.

So...

> One used to have credit cards, but dropped them off them in the designated boxes after they had attained their objectives

Comment: The question is about the use of "one" vs "a", not "one" vs "I". You can see the original sentence here: https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/450803/1

Comment: Thanks. I did in fact read the sample sentence properly though. There's no "a" in that text, hence I assumed "one" was to replace "I".

Comment: @GregorPurdie The word "one" is the 5th word in the quote. The OP is asking whether that word was a poor choice. (To reconcile the title with the body of the question, treat the quote as the result of the substitutions proposed in the title.)

Comment: Look, I'm really not here to quibble about the details, but the question specifically asked about the word "a", in quotation marks so it certainly wasn't a typo.

Comment: You've changed the sentence, the card is now plural. The OP was talking about a/one credit card, he did not dispose of more than one credit card. There has only ever been one card. He does not know if the indefinite article (a) can be replaced with "one", and he doesn't know if the simple past or the past perfect tense is needed.

Comment: *…dropped them off them…* is not grammatical, and how do cards attain their objectives? In your solution the cards seem to be living, thinking things.

Comment: Actually... Oh forget it. Well done you!!! ¯\_(O_o)_/¯